# Angularjs: restoring model value in $watch after failed update on server side

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here's the scenario:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vscGP/3/):

```
$scope.$watch('obj.value',function(val, oldVal) {
    if (val === oldVal) return;
    MyService.update($scope.obj, $scope.result).then(function(response){
        $scope.results.push(response);
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.obj.value = oldVal;
         $scope.results.push(response);
    });
});
```

I set a watch on a value and update it to db whenever it changes. But if the update fails for some reason (connection problem, server error, invalid session, insufficient permissions, .etc), I'd like to restore that value to the previous version. In the fiddle you can see what happens if you select "reject deferred" and try to change the value - it starts infinte loop of failed requests, restored values and $watch triggers.

For the time being I'm setting a flag on the scope to indicate that request has failed and next $watch should not call the service. But I'm looking for ways to reduce this boilerplate code.

Of course, I could always use some other ways to inform the scope, for example ng-change, but then I lose reference to the old value. I could keep the reference in my scope, but that is even worse than current situation.

Have you any ideas how these situations should be handled? Basically what I'm looking for is a way to update the model in the $watch without triggering further $watches, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use ng-change directive instead of the watcher, and use an internal state variable to store the value oft the last successful save.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/vscGP/6/

```
function MyCtrl($scope, MyService) {
    var lastSaved;
    $scope.obj = {value: "foo"};
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.result = "1";

    lastSaved = $scope.obj.value;

    $scope.sentinel = function ( value ) {
        MyService.update($scope.obj, $scope.result).then(function(response){
            lastSaved = angular.copy($scope.obj.value);
            $scope.results.push(response);
        }, function(response) {
            if ( lastSaved )
                $scope.obj.value = lastSaved;
            $scope.results.push(response);
        });
    };
}
```

---

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.value" ng-change="sentinel(obj.value)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a timeout or $timeout, you could also use a closure to encapsulate a boolean flag that you reset.

```
(function WatchWithRevert () {
    var justReverted = false;
    $scope.$watch('obj.value',function(val, oldVal) {
        //if (val === oldVal) return;
        if (justReverted) {
            justReverted = false;
            return;
        }
        MyService.update($scope.obj, $scope.result).then(function(response){
            $scope.results.push(response);
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.obj.value = oldVal;
            justReverted = true;
            $scope.results.push(response);
        });
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are doing it right. The watcher watches the watched object, so the best thing you can do is to tell it to close one eye for next watch.

You can use `$timeout` to set a temporary flag that gets cleaned up ASAP

```
_skipWatch = false

rollBackLocally = (newVal, oldVal) ->
  _skipWatch = true
  angular.copy oldVal, newVal
  # schedule flag reset just at the end of the current $digest cycle
  $timeout (-> _skipWatch = false), 0

$scope.$watch 'obj.value', (newVal, oldVal) ->
  return if _skipWatch
  MyService.doSomething().then 
    ((response) -> $scope.results.push(response)),
    (-> rollBackLocally newVal, oldVal)
```

Comment: It's in coffeescript, for terseness. But SO does not support coffeescript coloring....